# Regex to detect certain ASCII codes

Tags: regex

I´m not very good at regex, and I´m currently using the following method to prevent certain ASCII codes (40,38,9,13,27) from being put inside the input:

```
if(str.includes("(")) etc
```

Could anyone help me? The only regex I found prevented all ASCII codes, and that´s not the functionality I am after.

```
/^[\x00-\x7F]*$/
```

Comment: That regex will match those characters, are you trying to match anything except the characters in that range?

Comment: I want to match ONLY those characters

Comment: Aren't 9, 13 and 27 non-printable characters in ASCII decimal codes? 40 is `(`, 38 is `&`, what are the others?

Comment: (, &, TAB, CR and ESC

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to convert those decimal character codes to hex since you're using hexadecimal escape sequences. Then, you can create a character class that matches those characters and match with the global flag:

```
40 = \x28
38 = \x26
```

This will match if the input contains either character anywhere:

```
/[\x28\x26]/g
```

You can test in the browser console, assuming you're using JavaScript:

```
/[\x28\x26]/g.test('asldkf(jals')
> true
/[\x28\x26]/g.test('asldkfjals')
> false
```

The reason the above regex is matching ALL ASCII characters is because it's a range (denoted by the `-` between the escape sequences)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did this, but it isn´t working (and/or giving me false positives): 
/[\x28\x26\x9\xD\x1B]/g.test("ESC")

Comment: @David Your test is checking against the characters E, S, and C.  The code for escape is 27 in decimal which is 1B in hexadecimal so the escape sequence is `\x1B` and you won't be able to test with the string `ESC` you'll have to test with `\x1B`

Comment: I'm also not sure you'll encounter a lot of strings which contain the character code for the escape key but that's dependent on where they're coming from, etc.